# Bootstrap Cards Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to horizontally scroll cards using bootstrap V.5 like below

```
 <div class="container-fluid py-2">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
```

I saw a lot of working examples, but its not scrolling in my page ? I really donot know what is wrong here!
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Put `style="overflow:auto;` on the `.container-fluid` instead of the `.flex-nowrap` since that won't scroll. For an element to scroll, it's size should be smaller than its' contents.

Comment: You should close the question by accepting correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="container-fluid py-2" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap" >
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        <div class="card card-body m-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

#### Does this fix your issue?

Comment: how come this is horizontal?

Comment: if it works it works do not touch XD

Comment: it simply does not work, check the button to "run code snippet" it renders all vertically